# Personal project management software

Tags: project-management, workflow

I'm looking for a product to manage my own personal workflow. I use Office products for all the rest, such as Outlook.

**Required Features:**

- Outlook calendar integration
- Ability to have depend tasks and subtasks (so task is task a is delayed, task b end date gets updated)

**Optional Features:**

- Toggle integration

Comment: Assuming you want a Windows-based program? Are you looking for open source or within a certain budget?

Comment: Windows based would be great, but an onilne tool which integrates in gcal or outlook would be fine as wel

Comment: Sounds like OneNote would work, or does it not?